# Internal Server Error after ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');

Tags: php

After setting the memory_limit with php, I alwasy get an 500 Internal Server Error. I have no idea why, but if I don't my script gives me

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to allocate Y bytes)`

Any ideas how to solve this?

The script I'm using is to round the corners of an image (transparent corners)

```
<?php

function imageCreateCorners($sourceImageFile, $radius) {
    # test source image
    if (file_exists($sourceImageFile)) {
      $res = is_array($info = getimagesize($sourceImageFile));
      } 
    else $res = false;

    # open image
    if ($res) {
      $w = $info[0];
      $h = $info[1];
      switch ($info['mime']) {
        case 'image/jpeg': $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceImageFile);
          break;
        case 'image/gif': $src = imagecreatefromgif($sourceImageFile);
          break;
        case 'image/png': $src = imagecreatefrompng($sourceImageFile);
          break;
        default: 
          $res = false;
        }
      }

    # create corners
    if ($res) {

      $q = 10; # change this if you want
      $radius *= $q;

      # find unique color
      do {
        $r = rand(0, 255);
        $g = rand(0, 255);
        $b = rand(0, 255);
        }
      while (imagecolorexact($src, $r, $g, $b) < 0);

      $nw = $w*$q;
      $nh = $h*$q;

      $img = imagecreatetruecolor($nw, $nh);
      $alphacolor = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, $r, $g, $b, 127);
      imagealphablending($img, false);
      imagesavealpha($img, true);
      imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $alphacolor);

      imagefill($img, 0, 0, $alphacolor);
      imagecopyresampled($img, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $w, $h);

      imagearc($img, $radius-1, $radius-1, $radius*2, $radius*2, 180, 270, $alphacolor);
      imagefilltoborder($img, 0, 0, $alphacolor, $alphacolor);
      imagearc($img, $nw-$radius, $radius-1, $radius*2, $radius*2, 270, 0, $alphacolor);
      imagefilltoborder($img, $nw-1, 0, $alphacolor, $alphacolor);
      imagearc($img, $radius-1, $nh-$radius, $radius*2, $radius*2, 90, 180, $alphacolor);
      imagefilltoborder($img, 0, $nh-1, $alphacolor, $alphacolor);
      imagearc($img, $nw-$radius, $nh-$radius, $radius*2, $radius*2, 0, 90, $alphacolor);
      imagefilltoborder($img, $nw-1, $nh-1, $alphacolor, $alphacolor);
      imagealphablending($img, true);
      imagecolortransparent($img, $alphacolor);

      # resize image down
      $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
      imagealphablending($dest, false);
      imagesavealpha($dest, true);
      imagefilledrectangle($dest, 0, 0, $w, $h, $alphacolor);
      imagecopyresampled($dest, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $nw, $nh);

      # output image
      $res = $dest;
      imagedestroy($src);
      imagedestroy($img);
      }

    return $res;
}

imagepng(imageCreateCorners('img.jpg', 13), 'test.png');
?>
```

Comment: what do you do that needs so much memory for? Maybe you should ask for help to reduce memory usage. To me it sounds as if you have some infinite recursive algorithm or something similar to use all that and more :)

Comment: @EkimYardimli I added the script I'm using to the question

Comment: @CupOfTea696 What is the line no of the error?

Comment: @CupOfTea696 Also it looks like you are keeping `$src` for much longer than necessary - try moving `imagedestroy($src);` to the immediately line below `imagecopyresampled($img, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $w, $h);`

Comment: @DaveRandom no, I still run out of memory...

Comment: @CupOfTea696 on what line number? What is on that line?

Comment: @CupOfTea696 Just how big is this image anyway?

Comment: @DaveRandom Line 43, and the image is a 150x150px .jpg of 139KB

Comment: @CupOfTea696 is it intentional that you are attempting to blow the image up to 10x the size? I have just been playing with your script and I got the same errors as you, as soon as I changed `$q = 10;` to `$q = 1;` it worked fine.

Comment: @DaveRandom I have no idea. I haven't written it myself. I'll try it out (:

Comment: @DaveRandom That worked, thanks! The higher the number the better the quality of the rounded corners though. I'm using 5 atm, I'll test it with a lot of images to make sure it never fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @DaveRandom I got the same error as you with $q at 10 when i put a 1024x768 image it tried to create 10240x7680 which equals an image with size 78 megapixel with RGB that becomes almost 240MB

When I set the $q to 1 the code ran fine, and the resulting image had the corners cut nicely.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to allocate too much memory. Try cutting it in half until you stop having server errors.

Comment: I can set it up to 175M without getting a server error, but then I get Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 183500800 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24000 bytes)

Comment: Have you checked php_info() to see what the memory limit currently is?

Comment: Are you sure you have enough memory on that machine. Or when it is shared hosting that enough memory is available.

Comment: @Greg 64M according to phpinfo()

Comment: @PeeHaa I have no idea. I'm totally not pleased about my current host though, I'm changing as soon as the year is over.

Comment: Like other people asked, why are you trying to allocate so much memory? Maybe you should be writing some temporary files to disk and swapping if you need that much RAM.

Comment: @Greg It's just a script I got somewhere, I have actually no idea how it works, my php isn't that advanced. I'll add the script to my question.